# Shipping and Payment Filters does not appear

Tags: magento-1.7, module, payment, filter, install

I have installed [Shipping and Payment Filters](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-and-payment-filters-1454.html) using Magento Connect's installer. According to last reviews the module works with 1.7.0.2 CE but it does not appear on "Promotions" > "Checkout Rules" even after refreshing the cache and log out & log in again. I have also tried to re-install it. Can I do something else?

Comment: Check in the backend under System > Advanced (?) whether the module is listed under "Disable module output" so you know, whether it is loaded. When it loads, you can activate error reporting, make a space somewhere in the `config.xml` and check whether magento throws this error, if yes, the config.xml is loaded and you need to dig deeper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right link location is in the **top menu** > Promotions > Checkout Cart Rules.